# AuthorizeView Does not work when the user have 2 Roles

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

i have this check (in my frontend blazor)

```
[Authorize(Roles = "X")]
```

but my user have 2 roles, both X and Y role.

if he only have X role it works file. What i'm doing wrong?

```
my JWT token looks like this:
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": [
    "X",
    "Y"
  ],
```

here im adding the Roles in my API

```
foreach (RoleDTO role in roles)
            {
                claimsList.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
            }
```

is this not working out of the box or do i need to parse them inviduel?

Comment: The problem is the roles are being sent as one claim comma separated. The AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory Enet is suggesting transforms this to multiple claims.